# Python read multiline into a single line by reading a file line by line

Tags: python

I want to get the following files from

mwe.log

```
07:23:07.754 A
07:23:07.759 B  
C
D
E
07:23:07.770 I
07:23:07.770 II
07:23:07.770 III
```

I would expect

```
07:23:07.754 A
07:23:07.759 B C D E
07:23:07.770 I
07:23:07.770 II
07:23:07.770 III
```

by executing this code

```
import re

input_file = "mwe.log"


def read_logfile(full_file, start):
    result_intermediate_line = ''
    with open(input_file, 'r') as fin:
        for _raw_line in fin:
            log_line = _raw_line.rstrip()
            #result = ''
            if start.match(log_line):
                if len(result_intermediate_line) > 0:
                    result = result_intermediate_line
                else:
                    result = log_line
            else:
                result = result_intermediate_line + log_line

            yield result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    number_line = re.compile(r'^\d+\:\d+\:\d+\.\d+\s+')
    for line in read_logfile(input_file, number_line):
        print(line)
```

Should be used by python 3.7 and above. So my issue is that I would like to have each line with a timestamp like shown above so that I can postprocessing a single line. So it could be seen as an converter from a format 1 to a format 2.

Do you have any idea where I got the bug in?

Comment: What's the error / problem?

Comment: You always assign `result` to something new; never append to it.

Comment: I get the input file as a result

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger. You can use it to step through the code and inspect local state. Using this makes finding glitches in your code much easier. That said, read [ask]: Point is, that your question should state both what you would expect and what you get. Also, your code should be a [mcve], you could e.g. hardcode the lines from the file as a simple list.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - You could simply copy paste the file contents to a txt file since the question *is* about reading/writing files. Why the `list`? I agree with the rest though.

Comment: It's not about reading files but about processing them.

Comment: "reading a file line by line" is in the question. All I mean is I would consider this to be a MRE.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt you are right. Try to do this better in the future.

Comment: Why is it in the question? I don't see any indication that this is the actual problem. Maybe reducing this aspect of the code could have prevented this misleading part of the question. In any case, please chill, @not_speshal! This was just a suggestion how to make it easier for others to reproduce.

Comment: All chill here - just a suggestion to be a bit less harsh to the OP :)

Comment: @not_speshal I am fine. Thanks for the positive mindset behind you both. I agree that the tone could be seen as harsh. But anyway I believe the idea behind'sUlrichs comment is a positive one. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```py
import re

input_file = "mwe.log"


def read_logfile(input_file, start):
    with open(input_file, "r") as fin:
        result_intermediate_line = next(fin).rstrip()
        for _raw_line in fin:
            log_line = _raw_line.rstrip()
            if start.match(log_line):
                previous_line = result_intermediate_line
                result_intermediate_line = log_line
                yield previous_line
            else:
                result_intermediate_line += " " + log_line
        yield result_intermediate_line


if __name__ == "__main__":
    number_line = re.compile(r"^\d+\:\d+\:\d+\.\d+\s+")
    for line in read_logfile(input_file, number_line):
        print(line)
```

The problem is that you were always yielding the line, instead I only yield if the new line has a timestamp at the start, otherwise i append the line to the previous one.

Comment: I think this has one flaw though: You will print an empty line in the beginning because you yield the previous_line, i.e. the result_intermediate_line which will be empty in the beginning.

Comment: @Christian you are correct! I fixed it now (can just initialise with the first line). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could also parse the file entirely and `return` just once, like so:

```
def read_logfile(file, pattern):
    result = list()
    with open(file) as fin:
        for line in fin:
            if pattern.match(line.strip()):
                result.append(line.strip())
            else:
                result[-1]+=f" {line.strip()}"
    return "\n".join(result)

>>> print(read_logfile("mwe.log", re.compile(r"^\d+\:\d+\:\d+\.\d+\s+")))
07:23:07.754 A
07:23:07.759 B C D E
07:23:07.770 I
07:23:07.770 II
07:23:07.770 III
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, leveraging the power of `re.sub`:

```
import re
input_file = "mwe.log"
time_pattern = r'\d+\:\d+\:\d+\.\d+\s+'
new_line_pattern = re.compile(rf'{time_pattern}.*?(?=\n{time_pattern})', re.DOTALL)

with open(input_file, 'r') as fin:
    log = fin.read()
    new_log = re.sub(new_line_pattern, lambda x: x.group(0).replace("\n", " "), log)
    print(new_log)
```

Output:

```
07:23:07.754 A
07:23:07.759 B C D E
07:23:07.770 I
07:23:07.770 II
07:23:07.770 III
```

Answer (score 1):

you initialize the variable "result_intermediate_line" with value '' ...
...and never change this.

so the concatenation

```
result = result_intermediate_line + log_line
```

doesn't have any effect.